# What is Pressley and Segal's "basic inner product" for compact simple Lie algebras of types B and C?

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras, inner-product, loop-groups

In Pressley and Segal's book *Loop Groups*, they define a "basic inner product" $\langle-,-\rangle$ on a simple Lie algebra to be (minus) the Killing form scaled so that $\langle h_\alpha,h_\alpha\rangle=2$ where $h_\alpha$ is the coroot associated to a long root.

[**Aside** I believe there is some terminological confusion possible here: they surely mean $h_\alpha$ to be an element of the Lie algebra, rather than an element of $\mathfrak{t}^*$; Terry Tao [defines a coroot](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/04/27/notes-on-the-classification-of-complex-lie-algebras/#more-6629) to be such a thing, appropriately scaled. But others take a coroot to be a rescaled root, for instance [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system#The_dual_root_system).]

They give the examples of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ and $\mathfrak{so}(2n)$, which are $-\mathrm{tr}(XY)$ and $-\frac12\mathrm{tr}(XY)$, respectively. To avoid confusion, this trace is taken in the defining representation, thinking of these as matrix Lie groups.

But I haven't been able to find a source that gives the basic inner product for $\mathfrak{so}(2n+1)$ or $\mathfrak{sp}(n)$, where the latter are given as $n\times n$ quaternionic matrices. Once one knows the appropriate matrices $h_\alpha$, then it is obvious. And it is sufficient to know these for low ranks, for instance $\mathfrak{so}(5)$, since then matters stablise.

I tried asking for these actual matrices over at M.SE, but despite rather a detailed answer, I still have no joy, as it presumes a lot of "common knowledge" of Lie theory I don't have, and also is slightly loose with terminology and suggestions. I was hoping for something super explicit like writing out the analogues of the Pauli matrices. This seemed like material too basic for MO, but despite a lot of searching, no lecture notes or textbook I've found actually gives this information! Nor have I found student exercises that ask for them. To me this seems like a perfect example of what MO was intended for: a place for researchers to ask colleagues about a basic fact they need from an area they are unfamiliar with. So I'm cutting my losses, forgetting the exercise of trying to work this stuff out for myself, and asking outright:

> What is the basic inner product on $\mathfrak{so}(2n+1)$ and $\mathfrak{sp}(n)$?

My motivation is that eventually I'm going to be doing physics-style calculations, and need explicit representatives for absolutely everything. So a characterisation in terms of anything else is insufficient: I want a formula. A reference to a place where this is recorded in the literature would be the best answer, but I despair that such a thing exists.

Comment: Isn't this effectively just asking for the normalization of the quadratic Casimir operators for those algebras?  All the necessary quantities are probably to be found here:  http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph251/Casimir2.pdf

Comment: @Buzz if I knew, I wouldn't be asking! And let me point out my question asked for the actual formula, not other quantities. If this is so simple, why won't someone put their money where their mouth is, and write it down?

Comment: @Buzz that document (which I have consulted) works with a different convention, and only at the very end pays lip service to what I want here. It also calls the trace form a metric, but this is negative definite, so it's not clear to me what hidden assumptions are being used.

Comment: @Buzz apologies if that sounds harsh, I shouldn't be taking out my frustrations, generated elsewhere, on users here!

Comment: No problem; I see much more bitter complaints on the Physics Stack Exchange site all the time.

Comment: Note that there is no difference between the definitions of a coroot in Tao's notes and in Wikipedia. Both the roots and the coroots live in $\mathfrak{h}^*$, the dual of the Cartan subalgebra of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. The difference is that Tao repeatedly points out that $\mathfrak{h}^*$ is where the (co)roots live, but in Wikipedia, that fact is buried in the subsection "Root systems arising from semisimple Lie algebras", which is a few sections above where the dual root system is defined.

Comment: @ulnor Tao explicitly writes "$H_\alpha$ is the co-root of $\alpha$, defined as the element of $\mathfrak h$ given by the formula ...", but is taking roots to live in $\mathfrak{h}^*$. Check for yourself :-) And given that WP defines roots to live in $\mathfrak{h}^*$, and coroots to be scaled roots in the same vector space (as at the link I supplied), then coroots live in  $\mathfrak{h}^*$, as you point out. The source Konrad supplies defines coroots to live in the original Lie algebra, but many other sources define coroots to be in the dual of the Cartan subalgebra. So... :-)

Comment: @ulnor I checked, and Tao only gives a formula saying coroots are in the same space as roots _after_ using the Killing form to construct an isomorphism $\mathfrak{h}^*\simeq \mathfrak{h}$ (this simplifies the formula he gives that _defines_ the coroots (written "co-roots" on the page; he uses both forms). So there is legitimately some kind of convention in both directions in the literature, I would guess.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Pressley and Segal used the same identification as well, so it's probably not that big of a deal (if your Lie algebras are finite-dimensional): as Konrad says, it then becomes "merely a matter of taste". If you also look at the definition Tao gave for $H_{\alpha}$ that you've cited, you'll find that "co-root" links back to the WP article! To be sure, I think it's good to note that there are two different definitions.

Comment: @ulnor it does link back to WP, but the link is broken. I didn't feel like trying to check the article history to see what the page said back when the post was written :-) I agree there is perhaps no single good answer, but it's confusing as anything, and feels like there are potential pitfalls from combining sources with different conventions.

Comment: @DavidRoberts The WP link works fine for me, and a check of the history shows the content to be pretty much the same.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I should also correct my previous comment. There aren't two definitions in Tao's notes: there's only one definition, but it looks different depending on whether the Cartan subalgebra is identified with its dual. The definition in eq. (14) of Tao's notes normalises the co-root using the evaluation of the root on an element of $\mathfrak{h}$; this is the original definition in the section on root spaces. The subsequent definition in eq. (20), in the section on Chevalley bases, makes that identification, which turns the evaluation into an inner product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a reference that gave the correct inner products explicitly, without requiring the reader to assemble the relevant facts: Chapter II, section 1.2 (bottom of page 583) of:

- McKenzie Y. Wang, Wolfgang Ziller, *On normal homogeneous Einstein manifolds*, Annales scientifiques de l'École Normale Supérieure, Série 4, Tome **18** (1985) no. 4, pp. 563-633. https://doi.org/10.24033/asens.1497

Giving:

- $\mathfrak{su}(n)$: $-\mathrm{tr}(AB)$
- $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ ($n\geq 5$): $-\frac12 \mathrm{tr}(AB)$; and for $\mathfrak{so}(3)$: $-\frac14 \mathrm{tr}(AB)$
- $\mathfrak{sp}(n)$: $- \mathrm{Tr}(AB)$

Here the trace $\mathrm{Tr}$ for quaternion matrices is the *reduced* trace, namely $\mathrm{Tr}(X) = 2\Re \mathrm{tr}_{\mathbb{H}}(X)$, which can be checked by looking at the Dynkin index of the embedding $\mathfrak{sp}(2) \hookrightarrow \mathfrak{su}(4)$, which is 1, and the index of the standard embeddings $\mathfrak{sp}(n) \hookrightarrow \mathfrak{su}(n+1)$ (also 1).

Answer (score 8):

Section 4 of

*Gawȩdzki, Krzysztof; Reis, Nuno*, [**Basic gerbe over non-simply connected compact groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.geomphys.2003.11.004), J. Geom. Phys. 50, No. 1-4, 28-55 (2004). [ZBL1067.22009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1067.22009).

lists, in an absolutely concrete way, the simple Lie algebras realized as matrix Lie algebras, together with all roots and coroots. From these you can get the normalization.

For example, let's look at $\mathfrak{so}(2n+1)$. Let $e_i$ be the $(2r+1)\times (2r+1)$ matrix with a block
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0 &-1\\1& 0\end{pmatrix}
$$
on the diagonal at the $(2i-1)$th and $2i$th position. Then, the roots are the matrices $\pm e_i \pm e_j$ for $i\neq j$ and $\pm e_i$, and the coroots are $\pm e_i \pm e_j$ for $i\neq j$ and $\pm 2e_i$. You can check that $\mathrm{tr}(X^2)=-4$ for all coroots $X$. Thus, the basic inner product for $\mathfrak{so}(2n+1)$ is
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}(XY)
$$
just as in the even case.

Comment: Oh, excellent, thanks!

Comment: The remaining problem is thus to get the type C one, using quaternionic matrices. Section 4.3 has "With the invariant form normalized so that..." and then gives the roots relative to that. I guess working out the case of sp(2) shouldn't be too awful... If you feel like also giving this as an answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4430933/explicit-matrices-h-alpha-that-correspond-to-the-long-roots-alpha-in-a-cla/, that would be awesome.

Comment: My only worry is this: "We identify in the standard way t and g with their duals using the ad-invariant bilinear form tr XY on g. The normalization of tr is chosen so that the long roots viewed as elements of t have length squared 2", so that the isomorphism between t and t* might not be not the usual one that doesn't build this in. Perhaps my worries are unfounded...?

Comment: Here's something that confuses me: why are the long and short (dual) roots the same length in this metric on so(2n+1)? No, wait, how can you have tr(XY)=-4 always? Some of them should be orthogonal, right? What are your X and Y in this equation? Seems like a typo.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: yes, there was a typo, I meant $\mathrm{tr}(X^2)=-4$.

Comment: I think that the difference between roots and coroots is mereley a matter of taste here. The condition that the coroots have norm square 2 is equivalent to the condition that the roots themselves have norm square 2, when the norm is taken w.r.t. the same inner product used to pass from roots to coroots.

Comment: I'm not worried about the roots/coroots distinction, but the long/short distinction. (It might be that because Gawędzi–Reis' inner product is carefully pre-normalised, rather than taking the Killing form to identify $\mathfrak{t}$ and $\mathfrak{t}^*$, as I've often seen, but then again I might be imagining things)

Comment: @DavidRoberts As far as I can tell, Gawędzi–Reis seem to be using the same normalisation as what Pressley-Segal, according to your description, have done. Incidentally, I'm looking at the arXiv v1 version of their paper, and in that version, "viewed as elements of $\mathfrak{t}$" doesn't occur in the sentence you've cited above.

Comment: @ulnor I was checking the published version, which has such clarifying remarks added in more than one place. The whole exercise is to figure out the scaling on the inner product, by checking the length of some specific vectors. Rescaling the inner product first, so as to produce the vectors, is putting the cart before the horse. The ordinary Killing form always exists, and this is what I see people usually using to get the isomorphism $\mathfrak{t}\simeq\mathfrak{t}^*$.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I'm not sure I understand how rescaling the inner product first is somehow "putting the cart before the horse". As far as I can tell, this is exactly what Pressley and Segal did. This rescaling seems to be pretty standard and, as I understand from Tao's notes, gives the Chevalley bases.

Comment: @ulnor the exact point of my recent line of asking is to figure out how to get and verify the normalisation factor, using certain standard Lie algebra elements. If I have to normalise _before_ I can calculate those elements, how do I know what the factor is? I then can't _verify_ the definition since the elements I want to have length squared =2 will have it by virtue of my definition, which is plucked from the air. The definition of $h_\alpha$ doesn't require knowing the basic inner product, since it is done in many places without discussing the normalisation until later, if at all.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I think it might help to observe that there are very strong constraints on what can be a root (see Proposition 23 and Lemma 26 of Tao's notes, and the material immediately preceding both). In particular, this means that there can only be two possible lengths for a root in a non-simply-laced root system, hence the long/short distinction. Then the normalisation that Pressley-Segal referred to is setting the long roots to have length $\sqrt{2}$. The choice of this particular length isn't arbitrary, but a simplifying one made on the basis of the constraints on the roots.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: Ok, there was one more mistake in my reply: the roots are $\pm e_i \pm e_j$ and $\pm e_i$ (there was a "2" in front of the second type, which only comes in under passing to coroots). So these are the short and long roots. Your other obligation I do not understand: as written in my last comment, it does not matter how one normalizes the bilinear form used for identifying $\mathfrak{t}$ with $\mathfrak{t}^*$, or roots with coroots. The final normalization, i.e., the minimal one such that all coroots have length $2\mathbb{Z}$, does not depend on the normalization picked before.

Comment: @KonradWaldorf thanks for the correction. As I said: "Perhaps my worries are unfounded...?" I've been too busy the last couple of days to sit down and work through what happens if one uses an arbitrarily-scaled inner product to get the isomorphism to the dual, then fix up the inner product. Just cautious, with all the reciprocals of various factors flying around...